# Exclude Datadog integrating to a specific serverless function (AWS Lambda)

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, datadog

I'm having an issue with deploying lambda functions using the serverless framework. There is one lambda which is CloudFront edge function.

Using the "exclude" custom property, I have excluded that particular function. however, Datadog plugging still adding environment variables to the function and Cloudformation throws an error saying edge function cannot have environment variables.

How can I exclude the lambda function from the serverless.yml?

Answer (score 0):

If the the `exclude` function inside `custom.datadog` is not working, please open a ticket in the repository and I will address it for you: https://github.com/DataDog/serverless-plugin-datadog

Thanks!